# Div is unable to be made into link, any alternatives for XHTML strict?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

My inaugural post here, hope you all can help. :)

I have been working on creating a pure XHTML strict website no images but the products however I'm in a small jam. I can't seem to find a way to make the a button that appears as such as shown here:

[image]

Where it has a hover state, rectangle and currently is

```
<div class="topprodcartadd"><a href="#">Add to Cart</a></div>
```

I made a little CSS class that looks like this:

```
.topprodcartadd {
    width: 190px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding:0px 10px 10px 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.topprodcartadd:hover {
    background-color: #00a7e6;
}
.topprodcartadd a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00a7e6;
}
.topprodcartadd a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

I want to make it link somehow but in XHTML Strict it gives me validation errors when I rock the code like this:

```
<a href="#"><div class="topprodcartadd">Add to Cart</div></a>
```

So does anyone have any other ideas on what I can do to make the button appear that way?

Thanks!

Comment: Please confirm if you need this to be an actual link (having HREF that actually navigates somewhere) or you simple need it to appear as a link (cursor changing into "hand"). Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your CSS for the anchor to:

```
.topprodcartadd a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00a7e6;
    display:block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wZ986/)**

I added `display:block` and a width and height so that the link takes up all the room in the div.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I get your problem right:

1) you can set `display: block` for `a` so it fill the parent element.

2) are you sure that you need XHTML Strict?

Comment: Thanks chuwy. It seems like the display: block goes out of control for me sometimes. How would the CSS look inthat case if I did use it?

Comment: Yes, I have to use XHTML strict, it is one of the requirements of the client. :(

Answer (score -1):

If you simple need mouse cursor to change into a hand, just add `cursor:pointer` to your DIV's style, you don't have to use an anchor.

Comment: Except that has absolutely no effect like a real link and is purely cosmetic.

Comment: OP states he needs "a button that appears as such as shown here", it is never said that it has to be a real link that navigates anywhere.

Comment: No, the OP said "I want to make it link somehow".